# Constructing the new object of a generic type

Tags: scala, generics

How can I create the new object without the factory in this example?

```
def checkErrors[TResult, TError, TException <: Throwable](
  result: Either[TError, TResult],
  exceptionFactory: TError => TException): TResult = {
result.fold(
  err => throw exceptionFactory(err),
  ok => ok
)}

checkErrors(Foo.run(), (err: ErrorResponse) => new My CustomException(err.toString))
```

I would like to have something like this

```
def checkErrors[TResult, TError, TException <: Throwable](
  result: Either[TError, TResult]): TResult = {
result.fold(
  err => throw new TException(err.toString),
  ok => ok
)}
```

I tried to use ClassTag without any success and I don't want to use type erasure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can create an instance using a class tag like this:

```
 def foo[T: ClassTag]: T = implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass.newInstance.asInstanceOf[T]
```

You can also get other constructors and invoke them if the class has no default constructor. There is however no way to make this really type save and instead of type factories you would have to pass class tags around. So I think the factory is preferable. You can however use an implicit factory which might make things easier:

```
case class Instanciable[T](create: () => T)
implicit val stringInstanciable = new Instanciable(() => "hello")
def foo[T: Instanciable] = implicitly[Instanciable[T]].create()
foo[String]
```

This is typesafe and you can even have a much more complex instanciation procedure.